# (google chrome) why loading SVG's using <object> tags loaded one by one in angular 2, also they get reloaded each time I hide/unhide a component?

Tags: angular, google-chrome, object, svg

Please check this Plunker

https://plnkr.co/edit/qGr2Owj5wYZZMpp6lHuA?p=preview

```
<div>
  <h2>Hello  {{name}}</h2>
  <div>
    <img src="icon.svg" style="width:50px;height:50px"/>
  </div>

  <button (click)="showHideItems()">Show hide Items</button>

  <div style="height:10px; border-bottom:1px solid #cecece;"></div>
  <div [hidden]="itemsVisible" style="margin-top:10px;">
    <div *ngFor="#item of items">
    <my-item [icon]="item.icon" [itemName]="item.itemName"></my-item>  
  </div>  
  </div>
```

```
    //our root app component
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {Item} from './item';
import {ItemData} from './itemData';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  providers: [],
  templateUrl: "./app.html",
  directives: [Item]
})
export class App {
  public items:ItemData[] = [{itemName:"test0",icon:"icon.svg"},
                             {itemName:"test1",icon:"icon2.svg"},
                             {itemName:"test2",icon:"icon.svg"},
                             {itemName:"test3",icon:"icon2.svg"},
                             {itemName:"test3",icon:"icon.svg"},
                             {itemName:"test3",icon:"icon2.svg"},
                             {itemName:"test3",icon:"icon.svg"},
                             {itemName:"test3",icon:"icon.svg"},
                             {itemName:"test3",icon:"icon.svg"},
                             {itemName:"test3",icon:"icon2.svg"},
                             {itemName:"test3",icon:"icon.svg"},
                             {itemName:"test3",icon:"icon.svg"}];

  public itemsVisible:boolean;
  constructor() {
    this.itemsvisible = true;
    this.name = 'Angular2'
  }


   showHideItems(){

    this.itemsVisible = !this.itemsVisible;
  }
}
```

I am trying to load SVG graphics using object tag in angular 2 but the problem is that the object tags are loaded one after another. also if I hide/unhide a component the object tags get reloaded again, how to solve this issue.

using image tags does not have this issue.

Comment: Please show how you load them and how you add them to the DOM

Comment: You don't put the link to your plunkr :-)

Comment: The link is there, it's just that it's indented so SO treats it as a code block. I tried editing it but then you're asked to also post code from that plunkr, not just link to it. https://plnkr.co/edit/qGr2Owj5wYZZMpp6lHuA?p=preview

Comment: why did some body clicked the down arrow to give negative feedback about my question? the full code is there and the problem is shown clearly

Comment: I guess that's because you initially didn't add the code.

Comment: What does showHideItems do? Can you add the implementation of that to the question please?

Comment: it just show and hide the items. 
the full code is in plunker just you need to run it see the problem

Answer (score 3):

The "problem" isn't actually with Angular 2, it's with the way the object tag works, what's happening is that the object tag loads the img each time without caching it here the network tab in developer tools with the objects array enabled ...

[image: look how many icon]

And here is the same network tab without the object tag

[image]

So you either use something other than the object tag, actually if you don't want interactive SVGs you should avoid using it anyways and stick with the img tag, or you find a way to cache those images or hide them until they are visible.

Comment: thank you, I will check if there is a way to cache those objects, since I need interactive SVG's, that's why I used objects.